# Spark agent doesn't find External Shuffle Service in Kubernetes EKS

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm deploying Spark agents wrapped with scala scripts in Kubernetes. I want to use DynamicAllocation feature, which requires to have external shuffle service enabled in Kubernetes.

1. I have deployed a daemonset and a service for the external shuffle service

```
k describe service spark-external-shuffle  | grep IP
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                172.20.185.71
IPs:               172.20.185.71
```

2. I've modified the application config so it can take these properties:

```
          dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
          shuffle.service.enabled=true 

          kubernetes.shuffle.namespace = "default"
          kubernetes.shuffle.service.labels = "app=spark-external-shuffle"
          dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1
          dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
          dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5
```

3. I've restarted my app and I see a bunch of these errors:

```
12:46:16.599 ERROR [       TaskSchedulerImpl] Lost executor 60 on 10.0.8.56: Unable to create executor due to Unable to register with external shuffle server due to : Failed to connect to /10.0.8.56:7337
```

What I don't get is why it is trying to connect to random ip addresses like "10.0.8.56". I have tried to remove property "kubernetes.shuffle.service.labels" or tried to put wrong values and it still tries to connect to inexisting ip addresses.

EDIT.
Just for your information, shuffle external service runs Ok and opens the port 7337:

```
k logs -l app=spark-external-shuffle  | grep Starting
Defaulted container "shuffle-service" out of: shuffle-service, ubuntu-sidecar
Defaulted container "shuffle-service" out of: shuffle-service, ubuntu-sidecar
23/04/04 16:22:15 INFO ExternalShuffleService: Starting shuffle service on port 7337 (auth enabled = false)
23/04/04 16:21:36 INFO ExternalShuffleService: Starting shuffle service on port 7337 (auth enabled = false)
```

I would like spark agents can connect succesfully to the external shuffle service.
Regards!

Comment: I've just found those random ip address are the spark executors local ips. Which means that spark executors don't know that they have to find the external shuffle service endpoint. There is a miss-communication between spark submit app and spark executor.

Comment: From one spark executor I see this error log: ```23/04/05 14:02:42 INFO BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
23/04/05 14:02:42 INFO BlockManager: Registering executor with local external shuffle service.
23/04/05 14:02:42 ERROR BlockManager: Failed to connect to external shuffle server, will retry 2 more times after waiting 5 seconds...
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.14.235:7337
```. Executor wants to connect locally instead of the remote external shuffle service endpoint :|